# How to make form elements line up properly in bootstrap3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to organize the following:

```
FORM
TEXTBOX1

TEXTBOX2  TEXTBOX3
```

What is the proper way to do this assuming I start with a structure like:

```html
<form>
<label...>
<input type="text">
<label...>
<input type="text">
<label...>
<input type="text">
</form>
```

I see the  `class="form-inline"` makes elements within the form inline, but I just want the second and third textboxes inline and not all 3. What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: Please post the code where the part you create your form, anyway, I will use nth-child(2) + nth-child(3) to target the 2 textboxes.

Comment: It is in my post, but it is not showing up.... cannot tell why the post syntax is not working.

Comment: @Rolando, should be fixed now - you started the post with <form as the very first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this demo, if you want to achieve columns http://jsfiddle.net/tVHMy/2/

Relevant excerpt:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <label for="user_password">Password</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="30" type="password" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <label for="user_password_confirmation">Password confirmation</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="user_password_confirmation" name="user[password_confirmation]" size="30" type="password" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form class="form-horizontal">                                                                                                                            
  <div class="row "> 
    <div class="col-sm-12">                                                     
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="TextBox1"/>
    </div>                                  
  </div>                                              

  <div class="row">        
     <div class="col-sm-6">                                              
      <input class="form-control"  type="text" placeholder="TextBox2"/>                                                                     
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6"> 
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="TextBox3"/>  
     </div>                                            
   </div>                                                      
 </div>                                                    
</form>
```

Use the code snippet above to get the desired formatting